# Different symbols for square roots

Tags: symbols

Why are the square root symbols on [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/425632/31682) different? Some of them have vertical bar and other ones have slanted bars.

[image]

Comment: I see no vertical bars...

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, I've just edited to insert a screen shot.

Comment: I don't have vertical bars where you have. Then MathJax does different stuff on different browsers/OS?

Comment: I'm using Mozilla Firefox for Ubuntu, 18.0.1.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04/Mozilla Firefox 21.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is MathJax rendering not TeX so not really on topic for this site however you would see similar from a TeX rendering.

TeX fonts have a small fixed set of square root signs (typically with slanted left bar) but then once the term reaches a certain size, TeX switches to a use a glyph for the lower part and then repeats as many "extension pieces" of a small vertical segment as needed. This last mode necessarily has a vertical left side.

Comment: I think that I understood. Since the first four have fractions with both numerator and denominator containing parenthesis with powers, they have the same height and it was necessary to use vertical expansible bars. On the fifth, it does not contain `()^2` on numerator. Interesting! Thanks.